# iphone core data synchronization with ruby on rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, core-data

How do you suggest to a noob (in Obj c and ROR haha, I got some apps on both going but not very complex..)
to go about getting my next project to synchronise,

I have an app in the iphone that uses coredata to store the info (using  one to many relationship), working,

but I need to sync it to a ROR web app, so the user can send data from iphone to ROR and viceverza, and that if the user is offline (not connected to server,) when goes back again online, the data created or modified can be updated to or from the server,,,

I've checked the objective resource group, but to my dismay, is still a bit difficult (I have it running connected to the server but not stand alone)

what other option can I use?
is there a project that is on to  this?? (high hopes!!)

thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RestKit](http://restkit.org), it supports integration of Rails, Core Data and Three20, It hase many other features. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/).

Comment: Will RestKit actually sync?  I thought it would sync a record as it is requested or modified, but it does not maintain a full local copy of the database, just a smaller one for caching purposes.

Comment: You are right, you will have to do fetching and updating data your self but it is not very hard. As you can fetch all your model objects from Listing URLs and RestKit will insert/update its current records.

Comment: Right, this will cause all data to be locally cached, but it is not a two-way sync, and offline support will need to be carefully implemented.  It's only part of a potential solution to sync data, so the answer is a bit misleading as it is not a complete solution.  Syncing data is hard.